# Python (Django) based website not loading in browser

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I am trying to launch a pre-built website on a Virtual Machine's Server.
The virtual Machine has `Windows 2008 server` loaded in it.

The website i'm trying to launch is called RapidPro. It is open source and steps for deploying it for development is given in below link:

http://rapidpro.github.io/rapidpro/docs/development/

Although the instruction given in the link are for Linux (Ubuntu), I have performed equivalent steps in Windows and executed all the commands given in the link.

After executing the last command, that is:

```
 python manage.py runserver
```

I get the following logs on my command prompt:

```
C:\Users\zax\Desktop\RAPIDPRO\rapidpro>python manage.py runserver
modeltranslation: Registered 0 models for translation ().
Raven is not configured (logging is disabled). Please see the documentation for
more information.
INFO 2015-02-18 23:38:13,438 base 2872 1300 Raven is not configured (logging is
disabled). Please see the documentation for more information.
Generating LALR tables
modeltranslation: Registered 0 models for translation ().
Raven is not configured (logging is disabled). Please see the documentation for
more information.
INFO 2015-02-18 23:38:14,970 base 3520 2480 Raven is not configured (logging is
disabled). Please see the documentation for more information.
Generating LALR tables
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
February 18, 2015 - 23:38:17
Django version 1.7.1, using settings 'temba.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
```

So here i assume that the command was executed successfully and i can launch the website from the browser using the address `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`

On entering this address in my web browser (Tried on both `Internet Explorer` and `Google Chrome` browsers), The page doesn't get loaded even after waiting for a long time (15-20 mins).

On the browser tab i get the message:

```
 Waiting for 127.0.0.1
```

If anyone has any idea on what i'm missing, request you to provide it as an answer for the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the IP of your virtual machine ?

Answer (score 0):

I bet there is an issue with the firewall. If the request would reach the development server, you would see this in the terminal.

Try to open the port in the firewall, or (if there are no important other applications) try to disable the firewall for a minute, just to check.

Answer (score 0):

There is a parameter you need to pass when starting the application

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

This will start the server running on all available addresses on port 8000